# Sending multiline command output via wget as post-data

Tags: linux, bash, escaping, wget, sanitization

I'm trying to run a command that will send a POST request with data that is a result of another command. An example will say it all:

```bash
wget -O- --post-data=$(ls -lah) http://192.168.30.53/api/v2/network/clients
```

This is obviously wrong, but I have no idea how to "escape" the value of `ls -lah` command before passing it as a parameter.

Current output if needed:

```
wget: invalid option -- '>'
wget: --wait: Invalid time period '-r--r--'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not escape - you quote the usage. Check your scripts with shellcheck.

```
... --post-data="$(ls -lah)" ...
```

Comment: Oh damn, why I haven't tested it out before asking? Thanks. Somehow I was thinking that  it'd break anyway when double quote would be in the output, like the output of `ls` would be just replaced in place in the command.

Thanks.

Comment: how do wget "--post-data=" stdin pipe

Comment: Hi @CSQGB i do not understand your comment. The `--post-data` wget option is unrelated to pipes and unrelated to stdin.

Comment: How to use wget with the --post-data option and read data from stdin：ls|wget --post-data URL

Answer (score 0):

> I have no idea how to "escape" the value of `ls -lah command` before
> passing it as a parameter.

[`wget` man page](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/wget.1.html) describe `--post-data=string` and `--post-file=file` in unison, relevant for this case is that

> `--post-data` sends string as data, whereas `--post-file` sends the
> contents of file. Other than that, they work in exactly the same way.

and that

> argument to `"--post-file"` must be a regular file

due to above limitation piping stdin would not work, but that is not problem unless you are banning from creating normal files - just create temporary file for that, something like that

```
ls -lah > lsdata
wget -O- --post-file=lsdata http://192.168.30.53/api/v2/network/clients
rm lsdata
```

should work (I do not have ability to test it)